# binding member functions in a variadic fashion

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, std-function

I have a member function with a variable number of parameters, stored in a `std::function`, and I want to bind the instance and get an independent function object.

```
template <class T, class R, class... Args>
void connect(const T& t, std::function<R(const T&, Args...)> f) {
  std::function<R(Args...)> = /* bind the instance c into the function? */
}

// ...

Class c;
connect(c, &Class::foo);
```

For a fixed number of arguments I'd use `std::bind`, but I don't see how to do this for variadic parameters.

Comment: How exactly do you get `Args...`?

Comment: Okay, I wrote the code differently, hopefully it's more understandable this way.

Comment: Yes, it is. And makes the solution rather easy. :)

Comment: @Xeo That's what I like to hear :D

Comment: When you call connect() you also need to explicitly pass the types that will be used by the template.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you were trying to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <functional>

class Class {
  public:
    void foo(...)
    {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    } 
};

template <typename RES_T>
using ClassVarMemFunT = RES_T (Class::*)(...);

// Without typedef:
// template <class... ARGS, class CLASS_T, class RES_T>
// std::function<RES_T(ARGS...)> connect(CLASS_T& object, RES_T (CLASS_T::*funPtr)(...)) 

template <typename... ARGS, typename CLASS_T, typename RES_T>
std::function<RES_T(ARGS...)> connect(CLASS_T& object, ClassVarMemFunT<RES_T> funPtr)
{
    std::function<RES_T(ARGS...)> resultFun = [&object, funPtr](ARGS&&... args) -> RES_T { 
        return (object.*funPtr)(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
    };
    return resultFun;
}

int main() {
    Class c;
    auto funPtr1 = connect<int, float>(c, &Class::foo);
    funPtr1(10, 2.f);

    auto funPtr2 = connect<double, float, int>(c, &Class::foo);
    funPtr2(2., 2.f, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

In my implementation `connect` expects the actual argument types as template parameters. The `connect` function returns an `std::function` that expects arguments with `ARGS...` types.

connect has two parameters:

- one for the object that has a variadic function (`object`).
- one for the member function pointer that points to the variadic function we would like to call (`funPtr`).

We cannot use `std::bind` in the implementation (we could, but it would involve a lot of boilerplate to add as many `std::placeholders` as we need based on the `ARGS`).

So I introduce a lambda instead, that expects the actual `ARGS` typed arguments. We can return the lambda as an `std::function` and we are good to go.

https://godbolt.org/z/7cx3rcYh8

I created a version that can print out the variadic list as well:

https://godbolt.org/z/nMxj7Wh9j